# SpeedLimit:Using geocoder api the speed limit doesn't come in response and with legacy.route.cit.api.here.com the limit in response is in-correct

Tags: here-api

I am trying to use here api for getting speed limit for US roads. For the purpose I have create a free account and I am trying to get familiar with the services.

1. When I am using geocoder.cit.api.here.com api the search results doesn't reflect Speed limit however when the same search criteria is used on developer.here.com , speed limit is reflected in response

**Does in free account this feature is not listed?**

Rest Request: https://geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json?searchtext=Castro%20St%20Mountain%20View%20Santa%20Clara%20US&responseattributes=none&locationattributes=li&gen=8&app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg

2. When I use https: //legacy.route.cit.api.here.com/routing/6.2/getlinkinfo.json?waypoint=37.3936%2C%20-122.07909&app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg

Speed Limit comes is 11.18 which is wrong.
"Latitude/Longitude": 37.3936, -122.07909

Response sniplet:
"SpeedLimit": 11.18,
        "DynamicSpeedInfo": {
          "TrafficSpeed": 3.61,
          "TrafficTime": 12.5,
          "BaseSpeed": 11.11,
          "BaseTime": 4.1
        },
Why is it showing different result for same Latitude and longitude?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. As mentioned in [documentation](https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/geocoder/topics/resource-type-response-geocode.html#address) speed limit in geocoder requires additional authorization
2. The units for speed limits are different in the two APIs, the values are same 11.18 m/s = 25 mi/h

Comment: If you may please guide me on how to get this authorization.